# @ManagedProperty is not injected

Tags: jsf, managed-bean

`@ManagedProperty("#{sessionBean}")` is not injected properly. The `sessionBean` is declared in a JAR file and it has a JSF 2.0 compatible faces-config as well.
But when I use

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
sessionBean = (SessionBean) context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{sessionBean}", SessionBean.class);
```

It evaluates the session bean correctly. What is the reason?

EDIT: The bean that I want to be injected(sessionBean) is in a JAR file which is annotated as @ManagedBean and @SessionScoped. Also the JAR contains a JSF2 compatible faces-config in the META-INF/resources

Comment: Do you know that JSF uses setter dependency injection to resolve the managed properties? Do you have a `setSessionBean(SessionBean sb)` method? If no - that's a solution. If yes - provide us with a broader context. In any case you must describe 'not injected' in a developer-friendly manner.

Comment: Yes the setter is in place. I do not know what is the broader context other than that is explained in the question itself. Any way I edited the question to make it much broader

Comment: I am experiencing the issue described in this question.  I have put logging in the SessionBean setter.  It is not being called at all.  I'm following these instructions: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#InjectingManagedBeansInEachOther.  I'm using Mojarra 2.2.5 on in Tomcat 7.0.50.  I'd be happy to provide additional details upon request.

Comment: I'm using javax.faces.bean.* annotations, not javax.annotation.*.

Answer (score 1):

1.) Where are you injecting the `sessionBean` into? Show us the class definition. Is the class a `@ManagedBean`?

2.) Check if the setter `setSessionBean(SessionBean sb)` called.

3.) Is the provided value in the setter `null`?

4.) You can also try to do the following:

```
@PostConstruct
private void init() {
  FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
  sessionBean = (SessionBean) context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{sessionBean}", SessionBean.class);
}
```

... and check if the sessionBean is evaluated correctly.

Answer (score 1):

For me this was an issue with packages, the following imports worked for me:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
```

Before I was using a combination of different packages (auto-imported by IDE):

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
```

Comment: Indeed, the `javax.faces.view.ViewScoped` DO NOT work for retrieving `@ManagedProperty("#{param.id}")` you must use `javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped` instead. You nailed it!